# Периодические баннеры через localstorage js

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Я хочу решить задачу.
У меня есть баннеры которые появляются с определенной периодичностью.
Данные которых записываются в локал сторедж.
Для того чтобы на следующей странице не показывать баннер который уже был показан.
Но проблема в том что баннер показывается на следующий странице с задержкой которая указана у него а не с ноля.
Например на одной странице показано 3 баннера = это 3 сек
Мне нужно сделать так чтобы при переходе на следующую страницу 4тый баннер начинал показываться сразу а не с 4ой сек а сразу при загрузке страницы.
Помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhm8skf5/)

```js
let item = $(".some__item");

item.each(function() {
  var time = $(this).data('delay') * 1000;
  var timeclose = time + 10000;
  var itemId = $(this).data('id');

  if (!localStorage.getItem(itemId)) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).fadeIn();
      localStorage.setItem(itemId, time);
    }, time);

    setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).fadeOut();
    }, timeclose);
  }

})
```

```css
.some__item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 32px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 32px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #438842;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some__item" style="background-color: rgb(231, 161, 85); display: none;" data-delay="1" data-id="3123">Banner1</div>
<div class="some__item" style="background-color: rgb(231, 161, 85); display: none;" data-delay="2" data-id="3124">Banner2</div>
<div class="some__item" style="background-color: rgb(231, 161, 85); display: none;" data-delay="3" data-id="3125">Banner3</div>
<div class="some__item" style="background-color: rgb(231, 161, 85); display: none;" data-delay="4" data-id="3126">Banner4</div>
<div class="some__item" style="background-color: rgb(231, 161, 85); display: none;" data-delay="5" data-id="3127">Banner5</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сами привязали к каждому баннеру его задержку - `data-delay="2"`, а теперь собираетесь с этим бороться.

```
var time = 0;
item.each(function() {
  var itemId = $(this).data('id');
  if (!localStorage.getItem(itemId)) {
    time += 1000;
    var itemTime = time;
    var timeclose = time + 10000;
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).fadeIn();
      localStorage.setItem(itemId, itemTime);
    }, itemTime);

    ...
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за помощь, я понял свою ошибку